# Como chamar uma function do banco a partir do código

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

gostaria de uma ajuda,

eu tenho a seguinte function que está no banco `postgres`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_id(campo character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  _id integer;
BEGIN
  select into _id vlr_corrente from system_generators where nome = $1;
  if _id is null 
  then
   insert into system_generators(nome, vlr_corrente) Values(campo, 1);
   select into _id vlr_corrente from system_generators where nome = $1;
   update system_generators set vlr_corrente = vlr_corrente + 1 where nome = $1;
  else
   select into _id vlr_corrente from system_generators where nome = $1;
   update system_generators set vlr_corrente = vlr_corrente + 1 where nome = $1;
  end if;

  return _id;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.get_id(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Essa function gera as chaves primárias pra mim, para gerar as chaves primárias, só tenho que chamar ela: `select public.get_id('VENDA')`, ela me retorna um número único.

Até ai tudo bem, mas como eu chamo a function que está no banco, via linha de código usando `EntityFramework/C#/MVC` e me retornando o número.

Ou se possível eu possa gerar as chaves primárias a partir do código mesmo, sem precisar chamar a function, já tentei usar:

```
[Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

        public int id { get; set; }
```

Mas não da certo, aparece a seguinte mensagem: *"null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint"*

Obs: Não posso fazer dentro das tabelas, o auto incremento.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda !!

Answer (score 1):

Da mesma maneira que vc faz o SELECT.

```
var query = "SELECT functionName() as Result FROM Dual";
var result = con.ExecuteScalar(query);
```